Is there a difference between "true" and "real"?
Is there a difference between "true" and "real"? If so, what is the difference? I am asking because I have heard those words used interchangeably, but I am wondering if there is a difference between them. Also, what have philosophers written or discussed about this question? I would like to see some references.

This is a question better answered by looking in a dictionary.

They've been discussed by philosophers since ancient such as the celebrated liar. Is the liar sentence real? Is it true (or false)?...

It is true that my imaginary friend is unreal. But if that friend gives advice which proves to be true in the real world, it is less clear.

@DavidGudeman As can everything else be looked up — wiki, SEP... Why have the site at all?

@Rushi, word meanings are not philosophy.

@DavidGudeman   There is only 1 instance of the word 'meaning' out here.  Its in your comment. (Now 2 because I've repeated it). IOW you are free to force any philosophical question however authentic, into a word game. And we are free to not play along

@Rushi, I don't know what you mean by "1 instance", but if you had taken my advice and looked in the dictionary, you would have seen that there are multiple definitions for each word. Using some definitions they can be used synonymously; using other definitions, they cannot. It's all a question of English usage.

A statement is true, a fact is real.

This question is similar to: What is the difference between Fact and Truth?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I take this to be a question about the relation of the concept(s) of truth and the concept(s) of reality. As such it is not just a dictionary matter.

This is a real question! (Dunno if it's true)

I may be wrong here, but that all depends on the perspective of your guys’s reality lol. This question reminds me of a bit of wisdom. I came into it not so long ago. I came to the real)ization of, I don’t actually know anything unless I am able to feel it. Because what I can feel I know to be true. Unless I come to learn from someone or from another point of reality . Also like true and truth. When I know something to be true it’s real though it may not always start that way . The truth is set itself and can not be moved nor changed.

Typically, "truth" is used to describe propositions, while "real" is used to describe the existence of a thing. If X is "real" then the proposition "X exists" is true.

+1 Brief but the best response here. The OP should also be aware that 'truth' is a term studied by epistemologists. 'Real' is a term studied by ontologists. Beyond that, in a correspondent theory of truth, truth is defined in terms of whether propositions correspond to the 'state of affairs' or to some extent, an accurate description of what is physically real. Another theory of truth includes correspondence which is about matching truths among propositions.

One amongst many interpretations of the "real" and the "true", posted mainly to show the diversity available. (Since postmodernism the meanings are less rigid.)
In the quote below, from Kant's Critique of Pure Reason, B286, Kant refers to the real as the possible.  This can be put into context in, for example, if one is moving around in the dark feeling for possible obstacles.  These possible obstacles are real considerations and one takes them quite seriously lest they turn out to be actual.

The principles of modality are not, however, objective-synthetic,
since the predicates of possibility, actuality, and necessity do not
in the least augment the concept of which they are asserted in such a
way as to add something to the representation of the object. But since
they are nevertheless always synthetic, they are so only subjectively,
i.e., they add to the concept of a thing (the real), about which they
do not otherwise say anything, the cognitive power whence it arises
and has its seat, so that, if it is merely connected in the
understanding with the formal conditions of experience, its object is
called possible; if it is in connection with perception (sensation, as
the matter of the senses), and through this determined by means of the
understanding, then the object is actual; ...

The actual object encountered may be understood to be a door left ajar, but then the truth may turn out that is it a window frame.  Then again, the truth might be that one is still dreaming, or unbeknowingly on a holodeck.  Alas, what is true is practically impossible to ascertain.

“True” and “real” deal with different aspects of understanding and interacting with the world.
“True” concerns with accuracy and validity of statements or beliefs in representing narratives within the context of imaginary or real worlds. “True” is classical logical framework is boolean but it can be vague as in fuzzy logic. In natural languages trueness arises like waves.
Whereas “real” concerns with existence of entities and phenomena in the domain characterised by pain and suffering.

Outside any defined scope, you can argue that nothing is true and nothing is real, including God and our reality.
But in a more practical circumstance, for example, in the scope of your conciseness, some tenable relationships between "true" and "real" could be defined.
One can argue that if something is "true" or "false", it is not necessarily real.

+1 There is only one word in Sanskrit satya for both. The consequence: One of the most fundamental definition of God Satchidananda have multiple translations.

From a philosophical point of view, religion is useful as a concept, not as a dogma.
If God can create it once, it is much easier a second time.  :)

it?? What are you referring? Truth? Religion? Dogma is a peculiarity of Abrahamic systems. It is contingent to some religion not necessary to all.  See Open source religion

My religion is Simulation Theory. And great religions are an essential part of the Simulator's overall design.

Making your own religion is not a small matter!! Not too many can do it. OTOH everyone wily-nilly makes tweaks. The difference is building your own house from ground up by yourself vs. making non trivial rearrangements — furniture, plumbing, painting etc

This is a point. I am not making anything new. Praying God (Jewish or Christian or Hindu) works because this action triggers a response built into the Simulator's logic.

Understanding yourself, your origin, your purpose, your desires and abilities - is your personal matter. Culture, religion, parents and friends can only give you clues.

All true gurus say more or less that. In the eastern traditions guru is central. But all real gurus say: This is the way, but you have to do the work yourself. Work is summarized as the steps

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
